# Display all images store in folder using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display all the images in my image's folder.
This is my code :

```
 <% 
 string dir = Server.MapPath("Content/slideshow/images");
 string[] files;
 int numFiles;
 files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir);
 numFiles = files.Length;
                 
 for (int i = 1; i < numFiles; i++)
 {
 %>
 <i><a href="#">
 <img src="/Content/slideshow/images/image<%= i %>.jpg" alt="" height="239px" width="930px" />
  </a></i>
 <% }%>
```

When I code like this, it display only the images that have the name "image"+blah blah blah . But I want to render all images in different name in a folder.
Can anyone solve this?

Comment: There's so much wrong with this code, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: if this really is a mvc application you really are missing the point, you shouldnt be doing this kind of logic in the view

Comment: Actually, it is not in my View, It's in the Master Page.

Comment: @ O T A - replace the word "view" with "Master Page" in @Daniel's above comment and the same reasoning applies. DO NOT do logic in HTML where it can be reasonably avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public DisplayImages()
{

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Location);
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.*")) 
{
    //Do Something
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you using view models to achieve this. So let's start by defining such:

```
public class ImageViewModel
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

then we could have a controller action which will populate this view model (or precisely a collection of it):

```
public class ImagesController: Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Images()
    {
        var appData = Server.MapPath("~/Content/slideshow/images");
        var images = Directory.GetFiles(appData).Select(x => new ImageViewModel
        {
            Url = Url.Content("~/Content/slideshow/images/" + Path.GetFileName(x))
        });
        return PartialView(images);
    }
}
```

then we could define a corresponding partial view (`~/Views/Shared/Images.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#"    
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<ImageViewModel>>" 
%>
<%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
```

next a corresponding display template which will be rendered for each image (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ImageViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#"    
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ImageViewModel>" 
%>
<img src="<%= Model.Url %>" alt="" height="239px" width="930px" />
```

and the final part that's left is to include this child action somewhere in a view or a master page:

```
<%= Html.Action("Images", "Images") %>
```

Comment: Be very careful with input from users.  Just like with SQL injection, hackers can use code that enumerates the file system to hack websites too.

Comment: @Jeremy Bell, where did you see an user input in my example?

Comment: I didn't see anything with your example.  Just stating a general point of concern to the developer who was trying to enumerate the file system using in-line code from a View page.